# what logic used for iPhone app for tracing?

Tags: iphone, xcode, trace

I spend a lot of time searching for sample or document that helps me building a tracing letters App for iPhone.

I'm developing a small App for iPhone that helps kids to learn writing some foreign languages letters, the goal of the App is to display a letter and ask the kids to trace the drawing, each letter could include one or more path(s), ex. ("n" have one path, while "t" has 2 paths ).

Comment: The number of calls to `- [UIView touchesBegan:withEvent:]` equals the number of paths in the drawing, assuming that this is not a multi-touch application.

Comment: You could try using OCR (Optional Character Recognition)

Comment: for number of calls its ok. I can get your answer, but how I can check that the traced path matching the template ?

Comment: I thing OCR is ok only for English letters

Comment: hmmm... I wish I knew...